# How to know how many countries are in my regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, panel-data

I am running a linear model regression with panel data (20 years, 150 countries) in r. I see that 2,000 observations are excluded from my regression due to missing value. Some 4,000 observations make it to the regression.

I would like to know if any countries are excluded from the regression due to missing values. How could I find this out?

Answer (score 1):

Likes this:

```
    library(tidyr)
    countries_in_regression <- your_data %>%
    drop_na() %$%
    unique(name_of_country_column)
    all_countries <- your_data %$%
    unique(name_of_country_column)
    countries_not_in_regression <- all_countries[!all_countries %in% countries_in_regression]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
all(countries_column %in% unique(countries_in_regression))
```

This returns TRUE if all countries from the original column are in the regression countries, and FALSE if not.